# Create canvas shape connected to other shapes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Let's assume I have two rectangles drawn on canvas. Those rects are draggable. 
Is there a possibility to create a line connected to those two shapes which would be not dragabble itself but it's position would change if position of one of the rects would change.

So for example I have shapes with a line between them and I move one of the shape but the line is also moving because it's still connecting those two shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to keep 2 draggable rectangles connected with a line.**

Just draw a line from the center of one shape to the center of the other shape.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown=false;
var dragTarget;

var boxes=[];
boxes.push({x:50,y:25,w:75,h:50});    // x,y,width,height
boxes.push({x:200,y:100,w:50,h:50});


var connectors=[];
connectors.push({box1:0,box2:1});

draw();

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

function draw(){

  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++){
    var box=boxes[i];
    ctx.fillRect(box.x,box.y,box.w,box.h);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    var connector=connectors[i];
    var box1=boxes[connector.box1];
    var box2=boxes[connector.box2];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(box1.x+box1.w/2,box1.y+box1.h/2);
    ctx.lineTo(box2.x+box2.w/2,box2.y+box2.h/2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}

function hit(x,y){
  for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++){
    var box=boxes[i];
    if(x>=box.x && x<=box.x+box.w && y>=box.y && y<=box.y+box.h){
      dragTarget=box;
      return(true);
    }
  }
  return(false);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  isDown=hit(startX,startY);
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  dragTarget=null;
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  handleMouseUp(e);
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;
  dragTarget.x+=dx;
  dragTarget.y+=dy;
  draw();
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Drag the rectangles</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: This worked great.  I was able to convert it to work in React as well.  

What if we want the boxes to be a different color?  I tried using ctx.fillStyle = cyan, but then the black connectors show up over top of the boxes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to do that with the HTML5 canvas.

However, you could write such a system manually.  You would store the rectangles and line as JavaScript objects that knew how to render themselves on the canvas.  Then, you would install a mouse event handler on the canvas.

- When the mouse is pressed, you would store the mouse cursor's location.
- When the mouse is moved, you would update the locations of your stored objects based on the difference between the new mouse location and the stored location, then re-render the canvas.
- When the mouse is released, you would relinquish your stored mouse location.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was thinking about something like that but I thought that maybe there is a quicker solutiom ;) seems like I must write it by myself

Comment: I suspect there are HTML5 canvas libraries that will already do that sort of thing for you, although I personally haven't used any.